# Creating file with Bash scripting for loop and if test

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep

> Problem Statement 
>   Find files using bash script
>   In this section, you are going to write a script named findJane.sh within the scripts directory.

This script should catch all "jane" lines and store them in another text file called oldFiles.txt. You will complete the script using the command we practiced in earlier sections. Don't worry, we'll guide you throughout the whole process.

Navigate to /scripts directory and create a new file named findJane.sh.

> Mycode

```
#!/bin/bash


>oldFiles.txt

files=$(grep  " jane " ../data/list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3)

for i in $files:do

  do if test -e ~/data/"$i"; then 
     echo "$i" >> OldFiles.txt; 
  else 
     echo "File doesn't exist"; fi
done
```

output now
file does not exist
file does not exist
file does not exist
it should not print nothing 
and cat oldFiles.txt should return all those files with name 'jane

Where i am coding wrong

> Guide
>   Create the text file oldFiles.txt and make sure it's empty. This oldFiles.txt file should save files with username "jane".

Now, search for all lines that contain the name "jane" and save the file names into a variable. Let's call this variable files, we will refer to it with that name later in the lab.

Since none of the files present in the file list.txt are available in the file system, check if file names present in files variable are actually present in the file system. To do this, we'll use the test command that we practiced in the previous section.

Now, iterate over the files variable and add a test expression within the loop. If the item within the files variable passes the test, add/append it to the file oldFiles.txt.

Comment: For starters, you need to enclose the command that sets `files`, so `files=$(...)`.  Then, use the`-l` or `--files-with-matches` option to just get filenames.  Even with that, if a filename has a space in it, the `for` loop will split the filename.  (Person who put that space in the filename should be charged with conduct unbecoming of a human being.)

Comment: @Jack just a newbee please elaborate,your sarcasm is quite strong :).Looking for a clear answer.

Comment: Try fixing the `files=$(grep...)` line first.

Comment: you're on the right track. Fix the syntax errors uncomvered at https://shellcheck.net . Be sure to use `#!/bin/bash` as the first line when you post there (you're missing a `#` char). If fixing the syntax errors doesn't solve your problem, then edit your Q with updated code so people aren't wasting time commenting on easy fixes. Include exact text of any error messages generated. Good luck.

Comment: so far concluded it this step,anything wrong now

Comment: you can see the updated code..

Comment: As I said, you don't need all that `| cut ...` stuff.  Just use the `-l` option on `grep`.

Comment: Try with little steps. First try `grep  " jane " ../data/list.txt` and you will see the first problem"You don't want to look for lines with jane in the `list.txt` file, but want to look in all the files that are listed in `list.txt`. When the file is small you could start with `grep  -l " jane " $(cat ../data/list.txt)`. Did you learn about `xargs` "in this section"?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, just don't call the files by $in grep

```
#!/bin/bash

files= grep ' jane ' ../data/list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3

for file in files; do

   if  test -e ~/data/$file; then
     echo  $file >> oldFiles.txt;
   else
     echo "File dosen't exsist"; fi
done
```

And make the new fie `.oldFiles.txt` in the command line

like 
`user@linux: ~/program$ ./findJane.sh > oldFiles.txt`

The code shall work

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to do a Qwicklabs assignment, try this

```sh
#!/bin/bash

> oldFiles.txt

files=$(grep " jane " /home/<Student-id>/data/list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3)

for i in $files;do

if test -e ~/$i;then

echo $i>>oldFiles.txt;

else echo "not working"; fi

done
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to achieve? What errors/problems are you encountering? Please read this for help on asking a good question: [Ask]

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

>oldFiles.txt

files=$(grep " jane " ../data/list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3)

for i in $files; do

  if test -e ~/$i; then
    echo $i >> OldFiles.txt; 
  else 
    echo "File doesn't exist"; fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

you have just some typos. this is "working" code for your example

```
#!/bin/bash

>oldFiles.txt

files=$(grep " jane " ../data/list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3)

for i in $files; do

  if test -e ~/data/"$i"; then
    echo "$i" >> OldFiles.txt; 
  else 
    echo "File doesn't exist"; fi
done
```

however, this works only if `list.txt` doesn't contain any spaces except as delimiters between (at least) three columns

- it won't work for `Jane` because it doesn't match `jane`
- it won't work when there are more spaces like `jane   example.doc`
- it won't work for file names containing spaces like `best movies.txt`

it makes less sense to show how to do it right because the concept of list.txt is bad choice

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
> oldFiles.txt
files=$(grep ' jane ' ../data/list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
#echo $files
for file in $files; do
        if  test -e ~/$file; then
                echo "File path added !!"
                echo  $file >> oldFiles.txt;
   fi
done
```

Comment: Please correct your markdown and give some details.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

>oldFiles.txt

files=$(grep " jane " ../data/list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3)

for file in $files; do 
  if [ -e $HOME$file ] ; then 
    echo $HOME$file >> oldFiles.txt; 
  fi 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the path and then append it to the oldFile

```
#1/bin/bash
>oldFiles.txt
files=$(grep "jane " ../data/list.txt | cut -d' ' -f3)
for f in $files; do
 if [ -e $HOME$f ];then
    echo $HOME$f >> oldFiles.txt;
 fi
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a few fixes to your code and now works

```
#!/bin/bash

> oldFiles.txt

files=$(grep " jane " ../data/list.txt | cut -d " " -f 3)
for file in $files; do
if test -e ~/$file; then echo $file  >> oldFiles.txt; else echo "File doesn't exist"; fi done
```